# all-delete-orphan ignored?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have to import database from excel. A part of database looks like:

```
class Network {

   String externalId
   String name

   static hasMany = [phones: Phone]

   static mapping = {
      phones cascade: 'save-update,delete,all-delete-orphan'
   }
}
class Phone{

   String number

   static belongsTo = [Network]
}
```

Also I have a class that define excel record:

```
class NetworkExcelRecord{
   String externalId
   String name
   String phone1
   String phone2

   public def updateDomain() {
      if (!externalId)
         return null
      Network instance = Network.findByExternalId(externalId) ?: new Network()
      instance.properties = this.properties
      if (instance.isDirty() || !instance.id)
        instance.save(failOnError: true,flush: true)
   }

   private def getPhones() {
    def phonesOld = Network.findByExternalId(externalId)?.phones
    def phonesNew = []
    (1..2).collect {this."phone$it"}.eachWithIndex {String phoneNumber, Integer index ->
        if (phoneNumber) {
            Phone phone = phonesOld.find {it.number == phoneNumber}
            if (!phone)
                phone = new Phone(number: phoneNumber)
            phone.sortOrder = index
            phone.save()
            phonesNew << phone
        }
    }
    phonesNew
   }
}
```

But references Network - Phones are updated, but orphaned phones are not deleted. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `belongsTo` in your `Phone` class.  By defining `cascades` in the mapping of `Network` you don't need the `belongsTo`, as that defines only a save-delete cascade for the relationship.